# Custom Linq functions for sql and entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Is there a way to create functions for linq to sql that act different when used in linq to entities?
I do not whant to use a AsQueriable. I becouse I whant to do as much calculations on the sql server as possible.

example:

```
var UserIDs = Users.Select(x=> ConvertToString(x.UserID));
```

For linq to sql the code has to be:

```
public string ConvertToString(int id)
{
    return SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?)id);
}
```

For linq to entities the code has to be:

```
public string ConvertToString(int id)
{
    return id.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You do realize that the math processor of the server is probably better suited to doing data conversions and math calls than the SQL engine I hope?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlFunctions in Entity Framework 4 and above.  In your example, you do not have to do the conversion in the application layer.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/05/23/calling-database-functions-in-linq-to-entities-in-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Linq-to-Entites you won't be allowed to use the `ConvertToString` call in a query anyway, so this is a brave, but fruitless effort. The reason is that every statement in an L2E query must be an Expression that must be translatable to SQL by the query provider. And (of course) there is no built-in translation for any arbitrary method. L2E is very limited here. It is not even possible to use most native .Net methods like

```
Users.Select(x=> Convert.ToString(x.UserID)); // NotSupportedException
```

Linq-to-Sql is a bit more lenient in this. It will run the statement decently. But that does not help you, because you are looking for a common denominator. The bottleneck is L2E and it is a narrow bottleneck.